# Can't press back on googlemap

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

first post so be nice :)

My problem is that I have a class to open my phone Camera. However, if i press the back button on my phone, the app will crash.

Is there any way to prevent this? maybe just disable the back button?

Any help would be appreciated

This is the code I call to open the camera.

```
    btnpicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityIfNeeded(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

EDIT: This problem also occurs when I have another button to open the Gallery. The app just crashed if the Back button is pressed.

```
    btnsdpic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityIfNeeded(gallery, SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

Thanks Guys

Hemm.

Comment: When an android application crashes, it leaves an *error message* and *call stack* in `LogCat`. ***Make sure you you post them with your question*** (including the relevant lines of code the callstack refers to). My psychic debugging sense tells me you are _not_ storing/restoring important class state in the onSaveInstanceState/onCreate duo. Your activity is likely to be killed during the camera activity, so things crash with a Null Pointer Exception on the missing class state. But again... utterly guessing here, post more info for an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(camera, SELECT_IMAGE);
```

And:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image Caputred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image was not Caputred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image was not Caputred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting the Log Cat Paul-Jan, ill keep that in mind on my next post :)

Thanks Aki, That did the job for both of the issues (Camera and Gallery) :D

Comment: Just an fyi @aki143S you dont help people by solving their problem. You **DO** help when you provide some feedback and a small code segment, not the full code. Do yourself a favor and help the community get better at what it does by encoruaging people to learn through other means, **NOT** just by copying.